# Receiving an error on a python function: global name choice not defined

Tags: python

I have the following functions:

```
def Prefix(j,L):
    if j < 0:
        j = 0
    return L[:j]

def Suffix(j,L):
    if j < 0:
        j = 0
    return L[j:]

def Insert(item, L):
    if is_list(L):
        item = [item]
    elif is_tuple(L):
        item = (item,)
    elif is_string(L):
        item = item
        p = choice(L)    # Modified 
    return Prefix(p,L) + item + Suffix(p,L)
```

When I run the last I receive an error that global name choice is not defined, what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is you don't have a function (or anything else) named `choice`. Can you include the entire script?

Comment: Well, where do you define the `choice` function? Because it looks like the interpreter doesn't see it.

Comment: Perhaps you're trying to use the `random` module's `choice` function without `from random import choice` at the top of your script?

Comment: Also, `item = item` does absolutely nothing. You can remove that line.

Comment: Additionally, your `Insert` function will `return` an expression that includes `p`, but you only assign `p` if `is_string(L)` evaluates to a truthy value. If one of the other two `if` statements gets executed instead, you'll get a crash when the interpreter doesn't know what `p` is (unless it's a global somewhere that you haven't mentioned).

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you are trying to use the library function choice() which is defined in the random class. Here is the syntax to import this function:

```
from random import choice
```

Try adding this line at the beginning of your code and run it. Not sure about your purpose, but choice() function will return a random element, not the random index. From your logic looks like you are expecting choice() to return an index, so do so you can write your own choice function, in that case, you don't have to give above import statement. Here is the code for your choice function:

```
from random import randrange
def choice(L):
    random_indx = randrange(len(L))
    return random_indx
```

Write this function above your insert function, and it will insert the element at random position of L.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have any definition of the function `choice()` so python doesn't know what to do when it reaches the line:

```
p = choice(L)    # Modified
```

You'll have to define this function (or import it from somewhere) before it can do anything.